# ZedGraph scale all messed up

Tags: c#, charts, zedgraph

Using ZedGraph to show a price over time. Clearly I'm doing something wrong when setting up my graph. Any ideas?

Here is the code that I'm doing

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myPane = zgc.GraphPane;

    // Set the Titles
    myPane.Title.Text = "Forex";
    myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Date/Time";
    myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Price";

    myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Minute;
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "T";
}

private void QueryDB(ref PointPairList lst)
{
    if (connection == null)
        connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr);

    try
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        string pair = cboPair.Text;
        string sql = "SELECT bid, ask, price_datetime FROM forex.prices WHERE pair='" + pair + "' and price_datetime > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) ORDER BY price_datetime desc;";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DateTime tm = rdr.GetDateTime("price_datetime");
            double bid = rdr.GetDouble("bid");
            lst.Add(tm.ToOADate(), bid);
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

private void cmdRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PointPairList bidPrice = new PointPairList();

    QueryDB(ref bidPrice);

    LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Bid", bidPrice, Color.Red);

    myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
    myPane.YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;

    myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;

    zgc.AxisChange();

    // just points not lines. bigger points and colored based on
    // buy or sell. red for sell, green for buy
    //PointPairList tradeEntries = new PointPairList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after reading your code i found a piece of code that didnt look right for zedgraph meaning.

```
lst.Add(tm.ToOADate(), bid);
```

do you need to parse the date to OADate? if you make it an XDate you can use it as double

```
XDate tm = rdr.GetDateTime("price_datetime");
double bid = rdr.GetDouble("bid");
lst.Add((double)tm, bid);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a different axis type: 
  myPane.XAxis.Type = **AxisType.DateAsOrdinal** -> instead of AxisType.Date

This means that all points on the graph will be evenly spaced on the X axis.
ZedGraph will not use the date/time for determining the X values of the point, 
but you will still be able to see it (tooltip, maybe on the axis labels also)

Besides from that, maybe you need to set the myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit to DateUnit.Second, I don't know

good luck